# How do I change fluid material in a simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation

Been at it for a couple hours every youtube video they already have a material on their fluid but mine is just a bunch of particles not a liquid, I have 0 experience in liquid animations so any help would be appreciated as I could only find one other person with a similar problem, I did change the material of the cube that is the domain thinking it would change the fluid but it did not, yes the liquid still looks like that when I am not in wireframe, it doesn't even show up when I render.

[image]I would like to share my blend file but could not figure out how.

Comment: You need to check the mesh checkbox to turn those particles into a mesh, you can find that in the domain fluid settings window. Then you can change the material.

Comment: you would also have to bake the simulation.to attach the .blend file, you can go to https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

(It's already mentioned in the comments but to give this question an answer...)

You need to check the *Mesh* checkbox which you can find in the *Fluid* settings of the domain object. Then you can assign a material to the domain object which represents the fluid.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answser, and for the picture!!!